# How do I use Django's template extends variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

The django [template doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) mentions the following for extending templates:

```
{% extends variable %}
```

Where do I define the variable?  Is it from the views.py?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`{% extends %}` actually takes a string - the location of the template to extend.

If you want to declare this variable in Python, pass it in to the template loader using your dictionary. Example:

```
import django.http
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
# ...
INDEX_EXTEND = "index.html"
# ...
def response(request) :
    return render_to_response("myview.html", {'extend': INDEX_EXTEND})
```

And then in the view:

```
{% extends extend %}
```

Notice that `'extend'` was passed in the dictionary passed to the template. You can of course define the variable anywhere else in your `.py` file - or even in the dictionary declaration itself.

Remember that `{% extends %}` can also be invoked as such:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
```

Check out the docs on [**Template inheritance**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance), too.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's just a context variable like any other.

You don't need to use a variable - `{% extends "main.html" %}` is perfectly acceptable, in fact preferable unless you need to do something massively dynamic with template inheritance.