# change extends page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Can we pass a page name to a extends tag in django

i.e, i want to do something like

**EDIT**

```
 if(login):

     return render_to_response('/p_change/',
```

context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'page':'newpage.html'}))

```
else:
    return render_to_response('/p_h/',
```

context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'page':'newpage1.html'}))

```
 {% extends page %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to pass a variable to `extends`. From [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/):

> In most cases, the argument to {%
>   extends %} will be a string, but it
>   can also be a variable, if you don’t
>   know the name of the parent template
>   until runtime. This lets you do some
>   cool, dynamic stuff.

However, do note that there is a caveat!

> If you use {% extends %} in a
>   template, it must be the first
>   template tag in that template.
>   Otherwise, template inheritance won’t
>   work.

This means you'll have to place the page selection logic in your views (and not in your template as that will come before the `extend` tag hence invalidating template inheritance) and pass in the variable in your context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331148/how-do-i-use-djangos-template-extends-variable/1331183#1331183) for more details.

#### Update

In your updated question, your code is almost there, except that the first argument to [render_to_response](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) should be an template filename, not a directory.

I would rewrite what you have as:

```
if login: 
    sub_page = '/p_change/newpage.html'
else:
    sub_page = '/p_h/newpage1.html'

# 'base.html' being the base template containing {% extends page %}
return render_to_response('base.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, {
    'page' : sub_page,
}))
```

Of course, I'm just speculating on what you're trying to achieve and may well be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable to `extends`, if that's what you're asking.

```
{% extends page %}
```