# Base template for all apps in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a project with 2 apps

```
project/
    blog/
        templates/
            index.html
    polls/
        templates/
            index.html
    project/
        templates/
            base.html
            index.html
```

Now i want that the two apps extends the projects `base.html`. Is this the way to go? how it is possible and are there better solutions?

There is already an question which is handling this question, but it's only worth mentioning if you **dont** use split directories:
[Django project base template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720464/django-project-base-template)

**tl;dr:** I want to use split directories and want to know how to extend a base template from multiple apps without copying it to every app

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720464/django-project-base-template/60931532#60931532)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In current Django (1.10) [**TEMPLATE_DIRS** is deprecated](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/django/1.8/migration/template_dirs_deprecated.html), so:

1. Add a `templates` directory at the project root,
2. In *settings.py* find TEMPLATES -> DIRS and add it like this:

   ```
   TEMPLATES = [
   {
       ...
       'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),],
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Add a *base.html* to that directory.
4. Extend it wherever you want using `{% extends 'base.html' %}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Not sure when this changed, but `BASE_DIR` is a `pathlib.Path` object, so you could write `BASE_DIR / "templates"` instead of using `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Add a `templates` directory at the project root, and add it to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting.
2. Add a *base.html* to that directory.
3. Extend it wherever you want using `{% extends 'base.html' %}`

Comment: I've done that, my setting looks like this: `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),)` But that still doesn't work

Comment: Get rid of the forward slash.

Answer (score 3):

For Django versions above 1.8 the [upgrade doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/) suggests the vanilla settings (for most non-advanced django tangoers like me) be added to your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_Templates_Directory')),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Both BACKEND and OPTIONS were required, otherwise I had errors relating to 'INVALID BACKEND' and 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' must be in TEMPLATES'.