# Django: How to load a script for every page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Say I want to include bootstrap or angular for every single page in my views, is there a more elegant way than copying the same line to each file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django project base template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720464/django-project-base-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [django template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). Do the include in template `base.html`, and in there you define block that will be filled in for children templates:

```
<html>
    <!-- base.html -->
    ......
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- You include your js/css here -->
    <script type="text/javascipt" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</html>
```

then for all templates you extend `base.html` and override `block content` like so:

```
<!-- sub.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <!-- You current page html goes here -->
{% endblock %}
```

In this way, what you have included in `base.html` will be automatically inherited  and available in sub.html.

Comment: Can the base.html be open-ended? For example can it end with the css link without the </html> tag?

Comment: Well, template inheritance can happen among any two or more templates. As long as you feel like there's something in common for two templates and it would make sense to extract the common part into one, you can do it. You can even do `template 3` extends `template2` extends `template1`.