# Inheriting html code does not work properly

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I have a question about this part of extending a component from the base.html.
Let's say I want to use% extends in another html page, it doesn't load for me
Look
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i30Ns.png)

this is my directory project

In my base.html on container I have this:

```
{% block content  %} 
                
{% endblock content %}
```

And in next page, home.html

```
I have this
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
html code
{% endblock content %}
```

I uploaded to use templates / base.html but the same result
I do not receive errors or etc.
What other information would you need?

Comment: What view is rendering that template?

Comment: Which template does your view render? You should be rendering `home.html` if you want to see anything in that block.

Comment: Yes, and I gave an extends in home.html

Comment: take a look at this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720464/django-project-base-template
There are some important things in settings.py