# How to change template based on user authentication in django

Tags: django, authentication, if-statement, user-controls

If user successfully login i need to show one template. if user not login i need to show another template.

I created two templates one is `base.html` another one is `base_login.html` template.

IF user successfully login i need to call `base_login.html` other wise `base.html`. i am using below to achieve this. it's not giving expected result. How do achieve this?

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p> 
        {% extends "base_login.html" %} 
{% else %}
        {% extends "base.html" %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: your qury's is correct but i need to know whether you create the "backends or not" if not create a custom backend then try it

Comment: i created base.html file and base_login.html file

Comment: getting this error Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 
Invalid block tag on line 5: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: can you able to access the user in the template ? or try request.user ?

Comment: i am getting user name in html file

Comment: {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                                something not auth
                            {% else %}
                                {{request.user.username}}
                            {% endif %}

Comment: i thinks the error is coming bcz of the tags are in together {% extends %} and {% else %} . can you remove the else tag try it.

Comment: i removed else tag. now getting this error :Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: can you able to access the {{ request.user }} template ?

Comment: yes, i got the user name in template

Comment: {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                {%extends 'base.html'%}
                            {% else %}
                                {{request.user.username}}
                                {%extends 'base_login.html'%}
                            {% endif %}

Comment: i modifed but getting same error: Invalid block tag on line 5: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: is it possible to check ?

Comment: what type of check you want to do? if you skype id please provide.

Comment: id is djangorenjith

Comment: @SnakeFcz i sent request to you. please accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template goes invalid, I suggest you to it at the `views.py`, an example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

def homepage(request):
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    extended_template = 'base_login.html'

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        extended_template = 'base.html'

    return render(
        request, template_name, 
        {'extended_template': extended_template, ...}
    )

# homepage.html
{% extends extended_template %}

{% block content %}
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    Hello {{ request.user }}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

> **Note:** if function of `render` still doesn't work well, please try with `render_to_response` such as this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331183/6396981

Comment: here home means homepage

Comment: do you have skype id? please provide i will show you.

Comment: i want some help. when you will be available?